# find all address within a distance

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to retrieve a list of address + distance based on a specified lat/lng.

My query is:

```
@Query("Select new com.geolocation.AddressVM(A, "
    + "("
    + " 6371 * "
    + " acos( "
    + "     cos(radians(:lat)) * "
    + "     cos(radians(A.geoLocation.latitude)) *"
    + "     cos("
    + "         radians(A.geoLocation.longtitude) - radians(:lng)"
    + "     ) + "
    + "     sin(radians(:lat)) *"
    + "     sin(radians(A.geoLocation.latitude))" 
    + " ) "
    + ") as distance)  from #{#entityName} A "
    + "having distance > :distance")
List<AddressVM> list(@Param("lat") double lat, @Param("lng") double lng, @Param("distance") double distance);
```

However, when I run the query, it gives me an error due to unexpected token 'having'. I think that the 'as distance' is not seen outside the parentheses. Please help to correct me construct this query.

Comment: Is this a raw SQL query you are showing us?  I don't think JPA supports trigonometric functions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think it does, because when I remove the line "having distance > :distance", everything work expectedly.

Comment: I gave you two options below.  You may either repeat the distance expression in a `WHERE` (_not_ `HAVING`) clause, or you can subquery your current query and use the distance alias directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only MySQL and a few other databases allow the `HAVING` clause to be used without `GROUP BY`.  My guess is that this is not allowed here, hence you are getting the error.  One workaround would be to just repeat the distance expression in a proper `WHERE` clause, where this check should really be:

```
Select new com.geolocation.AddressVM(A,
6371 * acos( cos(radians(:lat)) * cos(radians(A.geoLocation.latitude)) *
    cos( radians(A.geoLocation.longtitude) - radians(:lng) ) +
    sin(radians(:lat)) * sin(radians(A.geoLocation.latitude)) )
) as distance
from #{#entityName} A
where
    6371 * acos( cos(radians(:lat)) * cos(radians(A.geoLocation.latitude)) *
    cos( radians(A.geoLocation.longtitude) - radians(:lng) ) +
    sin(radians(:lat)) * sin(radians(A.geoLocation.latitude)) )
) > :distance
```

The other workaround would be to subquery your current query, and then reuse the `distance` alias.  I won't write this out in full, but it would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    -- your current query
) t
WHERE t.distance > :distance
```

In this case, we can use the `distance` alias in the `WHERE` clause, because it has been materialized as an actual column in the subquery.

Comment: I have tried your solution on repeating the distance expression in the Where clause. It look a bit complex but it works perfectly. Thank you!